# Combining 2 For Each loops PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I am coding an application in PHP, which basically generates dynamic page based on User's input.

I have the variable's

```
$_POST['config'];
$_POST['configsize'];
```

Submitted as CSV, through POST Data.

My concern is to display the submitted data in a table.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr class="text-capitalize">
    <th>Unit Types</th>
    <th>Unit Size</th>
    <th>Get Price</th>
  </tr>
';  // end content

// add <li>
$amenities1 = $_POST['config'];
$amenities2 = $_POST['configsize'];
$amenitisArr1 = explode(",", $amenities1);
$amenitisArr2 = explode(",", $amenities2);

// add values to html
foreach ($amenitisArr1 as $str1) {
    $content_to_write .= '<tr><th>'.$str1.'</th>';
}
// add values to html
foreach ($amenitisArr2 as $str2) {
    $content_to_write .= '<th>'.$str2.'</th>';
    $content_to_write .= '<th>Book Now</th></tr>';
}
// continue in content
$content_to_write .= '</table>
```

I am getting the output,but alignment of table has taken a toss!!

Please help in correcting the data.

The Output should be something like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Unit Types</th>
<th>Units Size</th>
<th>Book Now</th>
</tr>

<tr> --- I want my For Each Loop to kick in here for as many times there is a CSV
<td>xxx</td>
<td>xxx</td>
<td>xxx</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Continuing further with my output:

```
$amenities1 = $_POST['config'];
$amenities2 = $_POST['configsize'];
```

This is the CSV. That will be posted from $_POST['config'] and $_POST['configsize']

```
$amenities1 = 2BHK,3BHK
$amenities2 = 1092 Sq.ft,2098 Sq.ft
```

[image: This Is the current output with the new code]

[image: This is the expected output.]

Image 1 is the current output. Image 2 is the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what output you are looking for, but I think you are looking for a table with 1 header row and 1 row for each of amenitiesArr1 and amenitiesArr2

If that is the case, the following code:

```
// add values to html
foreach ($amenitisArr1 as $str1) {
    $content_to_write .= '<tr><th>'.$str1.'</th>';
}
// add values to html
foreach ($amenitisArr2 as $str2) {
    $content_to_write .= '<th>'.$str2.'</th>';
    $content_to_write .= '<th>Book Now</th></tr>';
}
// continue in content
$content_to_write .= '</table>
```

Should be:

```
// add values to html
$content_to_write .= "<tr>";
foreach ($amenitiesArr1 as $str1) {
    $content_to_write .= '<td>'.$str1.'</td>';
}
$content_to_write .= "</tr>";
// add values to html
$content_to_write .= "<tr>";
foreach ($amenitiesArr2 as $str2) {
    $content_to_write .= '<td>'.$str2.'</td>';
}
$content_to_write .= '<td>Book Now</td></tr>';
// continue in content
$content_to_write .= '</table>
```

This ends each row. If this does not provide the output you are looking for, please provide a sample of the csv data being posted along with how you would like it displayed.

**Update for question edits**

According to the output you are seeking, you need a single for loop with an index.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($amentiesArr1);$i++){
    $content_to_write .= "<tr><td>".$amenitiesArr1[$i] . "</td><td>" . $amenitiesArr2[$i] . "</td><td>Book Now</td></tr>";
}
```

Be careful. This assumes that there are as many entries in the amenitisArr2 array as there are in the amenitisArr1 array. If that is not true, if there are less values in amentitiesArr2 - this will produce an error.

When dealing with for loops and tables, it is important to keep in mind that a single for loop will loop over rows. That is, 1 iteration = 1 `<tr><td>...</tr>` grouping. If you are including several columns within that row (like a database result), you can have a nested for loop to go over the columns.

In this case, the input is a single row for 2 arrays to be displayed over multiple rows with 1 value from each array present in each row.

Comment: Almost close. My output is something like this.

Comment: Please refer the question once again. I have updated the same.

Comment: I've updated the answer based on the additional information in the question

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `upload_tmp_dir` in your `php.ini` - it can not be set at runtime because at the time when your script begins running, the upload was already completed and the content is already stored in a temp file.

If you need to create the name of this folder dynamically - you have no other option than using `move_uploaded_file()` while first ensuring that the desired path exists (e.g. by setting the 3rd argument of `mkdir()` to TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two arrays by using array_merge function and loop once..

Comment: Can you give me an example Please?